# Trying to create clean url using htaccess but it is returning error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am really having a hard time figuring it out.

Currently my URL is looking like

```
http://localhost/projects/maxwink/blog-single.php?post_slug=test-2
```

I want to make it like:

```
http://localhost/projects/maxwink/blog-single/test-2
```

To achieve the task I tried the following code in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

#Removing .php extension

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Setting up URL

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ blog-single.php?post_slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

It is giving 404 error:

> The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.7 Server at localhost Port 80

Am I doing wrong anywhere?

Comment: do you have access_log and error_log for said site, might give you a clue

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file located? Your two rules certainly conflict. Are you using extensionless URLs for other parts of the site?

Comment: You probably want `^blog-single/([^\.]+)$` as second matching pattern ...

Comment: I'd really recommend looking into a PHP router script. Redirect _all_ files and directories that don't exist to a single file (often index.php) where you can apply all of your logic without configuring the web server every time.